# Using Or condition in Do While loop VB

Tags: vb.net, loops

I've got a Do While....Or.... loop that is as follows;

```
Do While headingStart <> -1 OrElse count <= 3
...[Statement]...
count = count + 1
Loop
```

However my count is going above 3 and the operation still occurs.  The operation only ends when the headingStart condition is satisfied otherwise an infinite loop occurs.

I've tried replacing Or with OrElse but no success - I assume it's a simple mistake I'm making?

Thanks
Hugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your text it sounds like you want to use the and operator:

```
Do While headingStart <> -1 And count <= 3
...[Statement]...
count = count + 1
Loop
```

That way the loop will only execute when both criteria are met. In other words, you will jump out of the loop if headingStart equals -1 OR when count > 3.

Comment: Ahh that's worked

The logic confuses me a little - as I associate AND with requiring both conditions to occur to exit the loop

Comment: @HughJanus `While` is a condition to continue the loop.  `Until` is a condition to exit the loop.